# Concatenate all fields within map

Tags: list, dictionary, clojure, concatenation

In clojure, I want to be able to concatenate all the fields(with a separator) in a map for each map in a list.

For the following result I want to be able to get:

```
(def h '({:key1 "one" :key2 "descone"} {:key1 "two" :key2 "destwo"}))
```

The result I want:

```
({one,descone} {two,destwo})
```

I did the following but I could not get the correct result

```
(def h '({:key1 "one" :key2"descone"} {:key1 "two" :key2"destwo"}))
(~@(apply interpose ","  (map (juxt :key1 :key2) h))))
```

And I am getting the following instead:

```
one,desconetwo,destwo
```

**Edit**

The scenario is as follows: We use jdbc to make get all the records from postgres. The records are returned like this: ({:col1 "one" :col2 "descone"} {:col1 "two" :col2 "destwo"}). Now, we need to concatenate all the columns with a separator and have this as primary key and insert it back into a new table in postgres.

Comment: Is the goal to return a list or a string?

Comment: It is not clear what is `({one,descone} {two,destwo})`? Could you be more specific?

Comment: Do you want _all_ values (subject) or the values of `:key1/2` in that order like in your code?

Comment: ({one,descone} {two,destwo}) is actually two records obtained by doing a  select statement (jdbc call) to postgres. The return value is a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to return a string since you talk about a comma as a separator.  I further assume that when you say "all the fields" you mean "all the values of each key-value pair", and that each value is a string.  In that case, the following gives you what you wanted.

```clj
user> (str "(" (clojure.string/join " " (map #(str "{" (clojure.string/join ","  (vals %)) "}") h)) ")")
"({one,descone} {two,destwo})"
user>
```

What the code is doing is first taking the values of each map and concatenating them with a comma separator and then enclosing each map with an open and close brace.  Then it is taking each such string and concatenating them with a space character and then enclosing the whole result with an open and close paren.

**EDIT:** To match the edit to the question.

Since you want to generate a primary key value that consists of all the value of a database row, what I'm assuming you want to return is a sequence of strings.  Where each string is a concatenation, with a separator, of all the values of each map *in a specific order*.  Assuming that is correct, here is a modified answer.

```clj
user> (map #(str "{" (clojure.string/join ","  ((juxt :key1 :key2) %)) "}") h)
("{one,descone}" "{two,destwo}")
user>
```

Comment: using `vals` is not really safe here, since in general you can't guarantee the correct ordering. (though for small maps it seems to be ok, itis really implementation details)

Comment: @nazar did not say, if it is (value-of :key1) (value-of :key2) or some more generic key-pairs. For the former I would be explicit about the keys, for the latter a sorted-map or any other type of extern "index" would be necessary.

Comment: You are both correct.  I have edited my answer to match the edits of the question and your comments.